# Android Studio not installing application into device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, device

I am making project on Android Studio. Now, when i Run the application on device, Android Studio failed to install it on the target device (not emulator).
 It is showing only this message:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-nexus_s-3133E2A0C87E00EC
Uploading file
    local path: /home/aaaa/Desktop/aaab/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.aab.aabc
```

Android Studio is not installing the application on device.
Please help.

Comment: Make sure the device does not go to sleep while the apk is uploading/installing. In other words, keep the screen on until the task is completed.

Comment: Device screen is on for 2-3 minutes.

Comment: Check your USB cable. Try using another one. Else, use wifi to upload apk. - http://joelifernandes.com/android/connecting-android-adb-over-wifi-tcpip/

Comment: How to upload apk using wifi?

Comment: There's a tutorial in the link posted in my last comment. Follow that.

Comment: has anyone found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue!

Comment: Updating Android Studio to latest version solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your installed apps list at the device.

1. If your app really isn't installed, try adding this:

   ```
   android:exported="true"
   ```

To the main activity at the `AndroidManifest.xml.`

2. In other case, if your app appears in that list but you can't find a shortcut to it, just add this:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

To the main activity at the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
I hope I've helped someone.

Answer (score 4):

I may be late and the question was answered for sure.
On my end the problem was as mentioned above the

```html
<activity android:exported="true" \>
```

in my manifest file.

happy coding day!!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using an app(NetLimiter) to limit the download rate and upload rate so has to manage the data usage that my PC is using. Immediately I remove this rule for my android studio. My app installed immediately

Answer (score -1):

2hours into this and i realized that my device didnt have enough space...
It have to have some free space to install some dependecies and other resources...